# Как спарсить ссылку страницы на Python?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, есть ли специальный метод, чтобы взять ссылку со страницы, на которой я нахожусь? Например можно написать

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.html.head.title)
# и выведется название страницы с тегами title
```

Есть ли такой трюк с добычей ссылки страницы, на которой я сейчас нахожусь? Может селениум сработает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `print(driver.current_url)`